# Mixer-Unit on Altera DE2-115 Cyclone IV

Tags: vhdl, fpga, intel-fpga, cyclone

I'm supposed to add to parallel 16-bits audio signals into a mixer-unit , then run the resulting signal through a parallel 2 serial unit , got 16 errors while trying to use srl functions and other stuff , could you please help ? After the code you will find a picture of the errors.
for this code i use the package [Audiofx](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s7dhhbkru5m7tpd/Audio%20package.rar?dl=0) with it

---

--  Institute of Microelectronic Systems
--  Architectures and Systems

### --  Leibniz Universitaet Hannover

--  lab :           Design Methods for FPGAs
--  file :          mixer_unit.vhdl
--  authors :
--  last update :

### --  description :

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

library work;
use work.fpga_audiofx_pkg.all;

entity mixer_unit is
port (
    clock       : in  std_ulogic;
    reset       : in  std_ulogic;`
    -- serial audio-data inputs 
    ain_sync    : in  std_ulogic_vector(1 downto 0);
    ain_data    : in  std_ulogic_vector(1 downto 0);
    -- serial audio-data output
    aout_sync   : out std_ulogic;
    aout_data   : out std_ulogic;
    -- Mono
    mono       : out std_ulogic_vector(16 downto 0);
    -- serial mono
    Serialmono  : out std_ulogic
         );
end mixer_unit;


architecture rtl of mixer_unit is 


component s2p_unit is
port (
    clock       : in  std_ulogic;
    reset       : in  std_ulogic;
    -- serial audio-data signals
    ain_sync    : in  std_ulogic;
    ain_data    : in  std_ulogic;
    -- parallel audio-data signals
    smp_valid   : out std_ulogic;
    smp_ack     : in  std_ulogic;
    smp_data    : out std_ulogic_vector(15 downto 0)
);
end component s2p_unit;

component p2s_unit is
port (
    clock       : in  std_ulogic;
    reset       : in  std_ulogic;
    -- parallel audio-data signals
    smp_valid   : in  std_ulogic;
    smp_ack     : out std_ulogic;
    smp_data    : in  std_ulogic_vector(SAMPLE_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
    -- serial audio-data signals
    aout_sync   : out std_ulogic;
    aout_data   : out std_ulogic
);
end component p2s_unit;

signal ain_left_sync    : std_ulogic;
signal ain_left_data    : std_ulogic;
signal ain_right_sync   : std_ulogic;
signal ain_right_data   : std_ulogic;

signal test_valid_right : std_ulogic;
signal test_ack_right : std_ulogic;
signal test_valid_left: std_ulogic;
signal test_ack_left : std_ulogic;
signal aout_left_data : std_ulogic_vector(15 downto 0);  
signal aout_right_data : std_ulogic_vector(15 downto 0);


begin
mono<= srl(aout_left_data,1) + srl(aout_right_data,1);
serialmono<= p2s_unit(mono);


S2P_left: s2p_unit port map ( 
clock => clock,
reset => reset,
ain_sync => ain_left_sync,
ain_data => ain_left_data,
smp_valid => test_valid_left ,
smp_ack => test_ack_left ,
smp_data => aout_left_data
```

);

```
S2P_right: s2p_unit port map ( 
clock => clock,
reset => reset,
ain_sync => ain_right_sync,
ain_data => ain_right_data,
smp_valid => test_valid_right ,
smp_ack => test_ack_right ,
smp_data => aout_right_data 


);
P2S: p2s_unit port map (
    clock => clock,
    reset => reset,
    -- serial audio-data inputs 
    smp_valid => smp_valid,
    smp_ack   => smp_ack,
    smp_data  => smp_data,
    -- serial audio-data output
    aout_sync => aout_sync,
    aout_data => aout_data,
    mono => mono,
    serialmono => serialmono
);
```

-- ERRORS are shown in the link

[image: ERRORS]

Comment: The error messages are pretty clear : what have you tried doing about them?

Comment: i'm stuck at the srl problem , i think i misunderstood how it works

Comment: The question does not state what "the srl problem" is, only that you get a bunch of trivial syntax errors.

Comment: i solved 6 errors by removing the shift_right instructions , but i still have to deal with the first errors

Comment: thanks for pointing these things out , i've edited my code a little bit and added the audiofx package with it so it is an MCVE now , as for the deadline thanks for telling me that , this is my actual first post and i'm here for learning , so thank you !